# take snapshot with webcam on Win10 with C#

Tags: c#, webcam

I am trying to figure out a way to take a snapshot with webcam using C#. I have made it work with CameraCaptureUI class, but I am wondering if there is a way to capture the snapshot without UI or any manual process. thanks.

Comment: are you building a winforms app?  (You should tag your question).  If so then have you looked [at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4953276/340045).  It doesn't have a single snapshot method, but it shows how to access the webcam directly through windows drivers.

Comment: @Ben Hello, thanks for replying, I am using the AForge now. It looks like it will solve my problem.